# Create a Rtree using a Map Reduce algorithm?

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, spatial, reduce, r-tree

In the current scenario, I Have a Rtree instance in which I add millions of records, which takes around  1 hr to create. I was wondering if I can use multiple mappers to create multiple RTrees & then merge them in the reducer to create the final RTree? Is there a specific merging Rtree technique available? How should I go about solving this? Any help is well appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered bulk-loading the index? Common bulk-loading strategies are based on sorting, which is well understood how to do in a distributed, scalable manner. This way, I've build R-trees with millions of records in just a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am completely new to the concept of R-Trees? So, can you please share any link which I can use to do bulk loading the index in java?